# Вылазит при добавлении .prepend()

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
var subMenu = $(this).attr("style");
var winWidth = $(window).width();
var alignC = $(".alignC").width();
var subMenuPos = $(".sub-menu").width();
var padHtml = $("footer").height();
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("html").css({"padding-bottom": padHtml + 22});
    $(".news-wrap a").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find("h2").css({"text-decoration":"underline",color: "#3498DB"});
    });
    $(".news-wrap a").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find("h2").removeAttr("style");
    });    
    $(function(){
        if(winWidth < 768){
           $(".bar-menu").bind("click", function(){
               $("body").css({overflow: "hidden"});
               $("div#hm").fadeIn();               
           });           
          $("#h li").bind("click",function(){
              $(this).find("ul").animate({right:"0"}).css({display:"inline-block"});
          });
          $("#hm").click(function(){
              $("div#hm").fadeOut();
              $("body").removeAttr("style");
          });
        }
        else if(winWidth > 769){
                  $('.h-menu li').hover(function(){                      
                    $(this).find("ul.sub-menu").fadeToggle().css({display:"inline-block"});
                    $(this).toggleClass("active-li");
                  });
      }
  });
});
```

Собственно попытался сам написать адаптивное меню, программирование знаю не очень хорошо.

**Сама проблема:**

В независимости от места вставки: `$(".sub-menu").prepend("<a class="back"></a>")`, выводит ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: r.phpPrefilter is not a function.

Самое интересное, что если ввести просто текст, то ошибок нет. так же нет ошибок. Без этого строчки в коде, ошибок нет, все нормально работает.

Может кто сталкивался с этим?.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка синтаксиса. Двойные кавычки внутри двойных. Надо так:

```
$(".sub-menu").prepend('<a class="back"></a>');
```

Comment: так  тоже пробовал, результат тот же